# Is directory error 21 for Snowflake ingest module

Tags: python-3.x, apache, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is the apache error log I am getting:

Python version 3.7

Snowflake ingest 1.0.1

```
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:41.883749 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] ['*****', '*****']
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.118090 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104] mod_wsgi (pid=15427): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/****/devops/apache_redirect.wsgi'.
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.118136 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104] mod_wsgi (pid=15427): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/****/devops/apache_redirect.wsgi'.
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119343 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119397 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/var/www/***/devops/apache_redirect.wsgi", line 8, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119401 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from devops import app as application
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119405 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/var/www/****/devops/init.py", line 7, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119407 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from ecomm import ingest_json as snowflake_inj
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119411 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/var/www/****/init.py", line 1, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119413 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from . import ingest_json
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119416 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/var/www/*****/ingest_json.py", line 6, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119419 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from snowflake.ingest import SimpleIngestManager
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119422 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/ingest/init.py", line 1, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119424 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from .simple_ingest_manager import SimpleIngestManager, StagedFile
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119428 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/ingest/simple_ingest_manager.py", line 12, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119430 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from .utils.network import SnowflakeRestful
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119433 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/ingest/utils/network.py", line 1, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119436 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     import snowflake.connector
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119439 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/init.py", line 21, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119449 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from .connection import SnowflakeConnection
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119453 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 16, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119455 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from .incident import IncidentAPI
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119458 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/incident.py", line 15, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119460 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from .network import REQUEST_ID
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119464 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 42, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119466 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from .description import (
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119466 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     from .description import (
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119469 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/description.py", line 20, in
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119471 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     PLATFORM = platform.platform()
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119474 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/platform.py", line 1357, in platform
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119477 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     libcname, libcversion = libc_ver(sys.executable)
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119480 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/platform.py", line 169, in libc_ver
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119482 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104]     with open(executable, 'rb') as f:
[Mon Feb 03 04:02:42.119492 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 15427] [remote 127.0.0.1:48104] IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'
```

Please add more details here:

Comment: ...and your question is? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a bit of guesswork, but if you are redirecting and executing a python script file, are the python libraries that are being imported in the script accessible in the redirected environment? IE do you have the dev libraries and the python packages available in the shared library?